# Bonfire for MySQL only? Bonfire Installation

Tags: php, codeigniter, installation, bonfire

Im planning to use bonfire on my current project so I have downloaded **Bonfire for CodeIgniter** and during the installation process it requires you to enter the database details like *host, username, password, database, prefix*

my project is currently using **PDO ODBC** in database configuration, and in my database config in my **CI** I have a path like **odbc:Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};DriverID=277;Dbq=...** this actually works in my **PLAIN CodeIgniter** now while installing my **Bonfire** providing these details i get the error

```
The installer could not connect to the MySQL server or the database, be sure to enter the correct information.: Unknown MySQL server host 'odbc' (11001)
```

What does it mean? so is **bonfire** just for MySQL? Im sorry if you find these very simple. Since Im new to Bonfire

Answer (score 0):

There  is already `odbc utility` installed in `bonfire` see reference [Bonfire odbc](https://github.com/ci-bonfire/bonfire-docs/blob/master/bonfire/codeigniter/database/drivers/odbc/odbc_utility.php)

Other way is have you tried directly entering database details in `database.php` which is located in `bonfire\application\config\development`

Comment: I've tried it, but still when I go ti `bonfire/install` I still get the page that requires me to provide db details, and Im stuck, I cant proceed since I think it just accepts `MySQL` host type

Comment: I have Windows 8.1 Pro 64bit Laptop. I want to install `Ci-bonfire` can you please advise me what is the best way. I tried lot of articles. But wont work. Can you explain it from the beginning.

Comment: @yeshansachithak you can visit this post [**`CodeIgniter Bonfire Tutorial Installation in Xampp`**](http://www.quizld.com/2012/08/codeigniter-bonfire-tutorial/)